# Replace a substring in a string with null in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string as

```
a='''123
456
789'''
```

I want to replace 456 with something similar to a null value, so that the corresponding output is

```
123
789
```

The objective is to eliminate the empty line that would be generated as a result of

```
a=a.replace('456','')
```

Comment: An empty string is different than the value of `null`, which python does not have

Comment: Try the newline character? `('\n456','')`

Comment: yes that works successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting *empty line* after doing *replace* because `'456'` is followed by `'\n'`. In order to remove empty line, replace `'456\n'` with `''` as:

```
>>> a = a.replace('456\n', '')
>>> print(a)
123
789
```

where initially `a` is holding the multiline string mentioned in the question as:

```
>>> a='''123
    456
    789'''
```